# Is it possible to parse command line arguments in JCommander without giving the name to argument?

Tags: java, parsing, cmd, command-line-arguments, jcommander

If I would like to run my app like this:
**java -jar target/App.jar 1928 start**
or
**java -jar target/App.jar 1928 start -d 3**, So how can I parse first two parameters, which would have no name, only values?

```
class Args {

    @Parameter(names = "")
    private Integer year;
    @Parameter(names = "")
    private String command;
    @Parameter(names = "-d")
    private String length;
    
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(year + " and " + command);
    }
}
```